# M_PI in C++ is giving me the incorrect value

Tags: c++, pi

Using the header `<cmath>`,
the symbol `M_PI` is giving the value,

`3.14159 26535 89793 11599 79635`

But the correct value for Pi is,

`3.14159 26535 89793 23846 26433`

So how do I get the correct value of PI from `M_PI`?

Comment: Floating point math is only accurate to a certain number of digits.

Comment: Remember that floating point representation cannot accurately represent all numbers and numbers like Pi are really , really hard to accurately represent. See [if `pi_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants) is more to your liking.

Comment: Look at your value of `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`.

Comment: I know it's often there, but was `M_PI` ever Standardized? I'm not seeing it, but my Standard-Fu's not the best.

Comment: @user4581301 `M_PI` was not, but C++20 added `pi_v` and a bunch of others: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants

Comment: `M_PI` is not pi - just the closest `double` approximation.  All `double` finite values are rational.  pi is irrational.  Cannot encode exactly.

Comment: That certain number of digits is given by DBL_DIG. Typically that's 15. Although by an annoying mathematical property, you get DBL_DIG + 1 96% of the time. You're in that lucky 96%. By the way, the accuracy you get is good enough to calculate the length of the orbit of Neptune to around 10cm. Not bad going really.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you.

Comment: If only the [Indiana Pi Bill](https://gizmodo.com/the-eccentric-crank-who-tried-to-legislate-the-value-of-5880792) had passed, then π wouldn't have all this awkwardness.

Comment: @Eljay I'm a big fan of changing the calendar to 13 months of 28 days. That leaves one day every year for recovering from the new years party and an extra leap day every four-or-so years.

Comment: @user4581301 • the [Tranquility Calendar](https://en.everybodywiki.com/Tranquility_Calendar) is one of my favorites!

Comment: @Eljay I knew I couldn't be the only person who did the math.